# Aligning output of echo command in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a simple batch file to parse a log file and print out the required data on the screen. I have everything working except for the fact that my output is not aligned properly as I would like it to be. Here is my batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
echo Name               Reg No.
echo -------------------------------------
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=' " %%A in ('findstr "Registered" registration.log') do (
     echo %%B               %%C
)
endlocal
```

The output is:

```
Name               Reg No.
-------------------------------------
Russel McDonald               28068906
Pete               23985688
David Antony               87681747
Jaques               71979798
Jayson Burgers               21343854
Allison Jameson               87446435
```

But I want the output to be:

```
Name               Reg No.
-------------------------------------
Russel McDonald    28068906
Pete               23985688
David Antony       87681747
Jaques             71979798
Jayson Burgers     21343854
Allison Jameson    87446435
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there a maximum length for how long the `Name` field can be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This batch code aligns the registration number on each output line.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Name               Reg No.
echo -------------------------------------
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=' " %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "Registered" registration.log') do (
    set "RegistrationName=%%A                   "
    echo !RegistrationName:~0,19!%%B
)
endlocal
```

I suppose that file `registration.log` is a tab delimited CSV file and therefore the character after `delims='` is a horizontal tab character.

The method used to align registration number is appending to name 19 spaces and then output just first 19 characters from name using a substring definition.

One more version without using `findstr`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Name               Reg No.
echo -------------------------------------
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=' " %%A in (registration.log) do (
    if /I "%%A" == "Registered" (
        set "RegistrationName=%%B                   "
        echo !RegistrationName:~0,19!%%C
    )
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`